# Force package version update when dependency package is updated

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget, portable-class-library

### Problem statement

We have a local nuget store with a list of components, which are used by a number of apps.

All of them always have a core component (let's say `PackageB`) defined as a dependency. From nuget graph perspective, we can say there's a lot of [cousin-dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/dependency-resolution#cousin-dependencies) in there.

[image: cousin dependency graph]

Let's assume core component `PackageB` has interface-types defined as `InterfaceA`, and `InterfaceC`.

`PackageA` has `ClassA` which implements `InterfaceA`.
`PackageC` has `ClassC` which implements `InterfaceC`.

`PackageA`, and `PackageC` both have defined `PackageB` as a dependency as shown in image above.

As part of an update, we made some changes in `InterfaceA`, and `ClassA`. Accordingly, new versions were created for `PackageA`, and `PackageB`, and we upgraded to these versions in our app.

We didn't realize that, another team had similarly made changes to `InterfaceC`, `ClassC`; and had generated a new version for `PackageC` - an update that we didn't need in our app. So we didn't upgrade `PackageC`.

There were no compile-time errors. It was only while testing the app, we started encountering following error:

> "VTable setup of type ClassC failed" (Android project)

The root cause for the issue turned out to be that when we updated `PackageB`, we ended up with the newer `InterfaceC`, which was no longer compatible with the older version of `PackageC`. **So, upgrading to latest version of `PackageC` solved the issue.**

### Question

To avoid this problem, I want to be able to force an update to all dependent packages whenever a core package like `PacakgeB` is updated in the target project.

i.e. if `PacakgeB` is updated, it should automatically force an update to `PacakgeA` and `PackageC`. Is this possible?

I am assuming that there is some specification which can instruct nuget or msbuild to handle this at app-project level.

Comment: Did you think about adding some pre build action to your app? I only used it for copy libs from one direction to another, but I think it is possible to add some script that analize package.config files and stop build in case of diff versions. It is like an idea, so I don't how implement it

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to specify right versions in app.config

Here it is my app.config from my project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="XLabs.Serialization" publicKeyToken="d65109b36e5040e4" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.5782.15703" newVersion="2.0.5782.15703" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

you will need to change `publicKeyToken` and set right version number

Comment: As per my understanding this approach will still need the package (PakageC) to be manually updated for the new assembly to be available for redirection. Manual update is what I am trying to avoid here.

Comment: Yes. This is only resolvse problem then you have different versions of same lib.